# Higher homotopy groups of the Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

How would you show that $\pi_n, n>1$ of the Klein bottle is the trivial group?

I was thinking Seifert-Van Kampen could be applicable?

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Seifert-van Kampen doesn't say anything about the higher homotopy groups.

Answer (score 8):

The universal cover of the Klein bottle is $\mathbb{R}^2$.  You can use lifting criteria from covering space theory to show that the Klein bottle and its covering spaces have the same higher homotopy groups.

Comment: So, then since $\pi_n(\mathbb{R}^2)=0$ for $n>1$, the result would follow, right?

Comment: @gabriel That's right.